# Xamarin.Forms (Android) Entry with full border

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is there any custom render solution, for customizing Entry for full 4 side border?

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/253205#Comment_253205

Answer (score -1):

Your error is that you don't have the defined resources. Either change the attributes from resources to hex values or define the resources for the current attributes.

Please refer to [Android Resources](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_1_-_android_resource_basics/)